# Group By - Incorrect syntax near 'mycolumn'

Tags: sql-server, syntax, group-by

I'm getting a syntax error in SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008) for the following query:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(EffectiveOn) AS EffectiveOn,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(Address4, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(Address5, ''))) Address4,
    PostCode,
    PolicyId
FROM 
    NameAddressCoverHoldingTable 
GROUP BY
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(Address4, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(Address5, '')))  Address4,
    PostCode,
    PolicyId
ORDER BY
    PolicyId, 
    MIN(EffectiveOn);
```

Error message:
**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'Address4'**

I can't see what is wrong - this works:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(EffectiveOn) AS EffectiveOn,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    --RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(Address4, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(Address5, ''))) Address4,
    PostCode,
    PolicyId
FROM 
    NameAddressCoverHoldingTable 
GROUP BY
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    --RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(Address4, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(Address5, ''))) Address4,
    PostCode,
    PolicyId
ORDER BY
    PolicyId, 
    MIN(EffectiveOn);
```

What is the syntax error?

Comment: Hi Pete, basic syntax questions are off-topic here on DBA.SE.  If  this were not already self answered I would move it to Stack Overflow for you, but I think if I migrate it now it would be closed as "Too Localized" there.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out shortly after I posted.  I need to remove the alias from the GROUP BY clause.

Solution:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(EffectiveOn) AS EffectiveOn,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(Address4, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(Address5, ''))) Address4,
    PostCode,
    PolicyId
FROM 
    NameAddressCoverHoldingTable 
GROUP BY
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(Address4, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(Address5, ''))),
    PostCode,
    PolicyId
ORDER BY
    PolicyId, 
    MIN(EffectiveOn);
```

Comment: Correct. You can use aliases in `ORDER BY` though, if you want: `ORDER BY PolicyId, EffectiveOn;`